# Scala case class and companion object can't override apply with diff signature

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
case class Foo(x:Int) {
  def this(x: Int, y: Int) = this(x + y)
}

object Foo {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = new Foo(x, y)
}
```

I received the compilation error: `Error:Person is already defined as (compiler-generated) case class companion object Person`
This code must work due to the fact that `apply` have an another signature. Maybe it's a bug in scala, my scala version is 2.11.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug for this ([SI-3772](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3772)). Should be fixed in Scala 2.12.2 ([here is the pull request which fixes it](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5550)).

You can work around this if you define the `object` in scope first, but then your `this(x, y)` constructor will be shadowing the companions `apply` method:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Foo {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int): Foo = {
    println("in new apply")
    new Foo(x, y)
  }
}

case class Foo(x: Int) {
  def this(x:Int, y:Int) = this(x+y)
}

Foo(1,1)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

in new apply
```

But that creates ambiguity, I wouldn't use that.

Comment: Why this bug was not fixed early, it looks like a serious defect?

Comment: @pacman It simply wasn't prioritized. Note you can partly work around the issue, see my update.